# Selection of an ARIMA model looking at the ACF and PACF

Tags: r, time-series, arima, model-selection

I am using the table below as model selection tool (at least as starting point)

[image]

Let's say that I choose a proper model according to the table and I get nice ACF and PACF out of it, but either my AR term or my MA term is pretty high, is there a way to simplify it?

Note: I don't know if it is relevant, but I am using R.

Comment: .......... see my answer

Comment: What do you mean by "either my AR term or my MA term is pretty high"? I assume you mean the AR or MA orders? This can happen with seasonality (and then you should be doing seasonal differencing), but otherwise [very rarely](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285093/1352).

Comment: Or perhaps I actually misunderstood the question... Could you clarify?

Comment: My question is, if after an iterative process I find a proper model but the AR or MA order (or both) is pretty high, should I consider a way to simply them?
If yes, how should I procede?

Comment: Could you try to make your title more specific? And also explain what you mean by "AR term or my MA term is pretty high"?

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that there is a presumption of no pulses, no level shifts , no seasonal pulses and no local time trends in your approach. If you treat the identification in a holistic manner , the ARIMA structure is often quite simplified and more correct. Additional assumptions are that both the parameters and the model error variance are constant over time. One has to read/understand the fine print.

Comment: I am not sure I totally understood your answer: but my question is not actually about the selection method; it's more about wheter or not I should take for good a model with high AR or MA order or if I should argue them somehow.

Comment: i would argue them by starting simple and proceed with an iterative self-checking process to build up the model to a point of sufficiency. The software/approach you are using to do model identification is probably way over-parameterizing. If you wish to post a data set and your model I will try and help further.