Problems with using ACF and PACF for ARMA modelling

This is the ACF and PACF for my the first difference of my variable $\Delta y_t,$ I used the ADF test, the PP test, the Schmidt Phillips test and the DFGLS test, and got the same result that my variable $\Delta y_t$ was integrated of order 0, but from what we've been taught, these plots don't seem to indicate that it is stationary.
I have been trying to fit an ARMA model on $\Delta y_t,$ the methodology we were taught is that you look at the highest significant lag in both the plots to decide the order of the AR and MA process, and then use the BG test for autocorrelation to parse the model down if there is no correlation.
My lag for the AR is 11 from the PACF, 16 for the MA from the ACF. I'm trying to parse down the model but get very inconsistent and unpredictable results. I'm using eviews and it didn't allow me to put so many terms so I started with ARMA (10,0,10). For ARMA(10,0,10), I get that the model is non-stationary since one of the inverted AR roots is 1, and there is high serial correlation among the residuals. But then for ARMA(10,0,9) I get that it is stationary and there isn't any serial correlation. For ARMA (4,0,2) I get that it stationary but has serial correlation.
I can't understand where I am going wrong. Please help.

ARIMA(10,0,10) is a huge model. Standard implementations do not go beyond order 5: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285093/1352. Also, have you tried a grid search to minimize an information criterion? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352

I tried to minimise the AIC value through auto.arima in R and got ARMA(2,0,0). But, the LM test shows that there is serial correlation. From what I have been taught, that means I need to the order of the AR process.

Your data are monthly?

No, it's quarterly.


I used the ADF test, the PP test, the Schmidt Phillips test and the DFGLS test, and got the same result that my variable $\Delta y_t$ was integrated of order 0, but from what we've been taught, these plots don't seem to indicate that it is stationary.

The ACF and PACF plots are very much compatible with stationarity. In presence of a unit root, the ACF would have lag 1 at close to 1, but now it is less than 0.3. It would also have lags 2, 3, ... declining slowly from close to one, but here they are all small and occasionally statistically insignificant. PACF would have lag 1 at close to 1, but here it is less than 0.3 So your ACF and PACF are very far from showing presence of a unit root.

The methodology we were taught is that you look at the highest significant lag in both the plots to decide the order of the AR and MA process

This is questionable at best. Stephen Kolassa indicates (somewhat indirectly) some more modern methods for selecting lag orders of an ARMA model. They that are more robust to overfitting compared to what you have been taught. I also agree with him that your models were quite large, except perhaps for For ARMA(4,0,2). And if its residuals contain some serial correlation, perhaps it is fairly mild? Squeezing out the last bit of autocorrelation by increasing the lag orders of ARMA may easily lead to overfitting.
