# Formula for an ARIMA(1,1,1) solving for y

Tags: time-series, arima, interpretation

I have an Arima(1,1,1) model with [predictors](https://www.otexts.org/fpp2/regarima.html) `var1+var2+var3`, but am struggling with how to write the equation. The problem is that on all of the sources I see a variation of the following is given.

$$\left( 1 - \sum_{i=1}^p \phi_i L^i\right)
(1-L)^d y_t = \delta + \left( 1 + \sum_{i=1}^q \theta_i L^i \right) \varepsilon_t . $$

Is there a way to write the equation solving for $y_t$? I find that the above equation is difficult to understand. Though I have the model saved in R the users of the forecast want the coefficients so they can plug them into excel and I don't have a good way to explain the formula solving for $y_t$

Comment: What do you mean by "predictors `var1+var2+var3`"? Do you have an ARIMAX model, or a regression with ARIMA errors? Or do you have simply a straightforward ARIMA(1,1,1) model? This earlier thread may be helpful, although it does not specifically contain an ARIMA(1,1,1) model: [Interpret ARIMA models in plain english](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/284648/1352)

Comment: Let me give a slightly different example with some output from R. Lets say I have an ARIMA(5,1,0). With the following output: `ar1=-.1,ar2=-.2,ar3=.01,ar4=.02,ar5=.03, var1=.5,var2=.3,var3=.6`. How do I write that as an equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "predictors `var1+var2+var3`"?

Comment: Thanks for you patience, `var1+var2+var3` would be coded as `Arima(log(train[,"sales"]), xreg=cbind(var1,var2,var3),order = c(5,1,0))`. Hyndman calls this "Dynamic Regression".

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies matters. This is a case of regression with ARIMA errors, see Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). I'll try to post an answer tomorrow and retract my close vote for now. Everybody: please leave open, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arima()` fits a so-called regression with ARIMA errors. Note that [this is different from an ARIMAX model](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). In your particular case, you regress your focal variable on three predictors, with an ARIMA(1,1,1) structure on the residuals:

$$ y_t = \beta_1x_{1t}+\beta_2x_{2t}+\beta_3x_{3t}+\epsilon_t $$

with $\epsilon_t\sim\text{ARIMA}(1,1,1)$.

To write down the formulas for $\epsilon_t$, we use the backshift operator. [For ARIMA background, see here.](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/5) A general ARIMA(1,1,1) model with AR parameter $\phi$ and MA parameter $\theta$ has the following form (note that some packages flip the sign of $\theta$, and that one sometimes fits a nonzero intercept $c$):

$$ (1-\phi B)(1-B)\epsilon_t = (1+\theta B)\eta_t, $$

where $\eta_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ are IID innovations. Some calculations show that

$$ \begin{align*} & \epsilon_t-\phi\epsilon_{t-1}-\epsilon_{t-1}+\phi\epsilon_{t-2} \\
= & (1-\phi B)(\epsilon_t-\epsilon_{t-1}) \\
= & (1-\phi B)(1-B)\epsilon_t \\
= & (1+\theta B)\eta_t \\
= & \eta_t+\theta\eta_{t-1},
\end{align*}
$$

or

$$ \epsilon_t = (1+\phi)\epsilon_{t-1}-\phi\epsilon_{t-2}+\eta_t+\theta\eta_{t-1}.$$

Comment: So in the end, this is the formula? $$ y_t = \beta_1x_{1t}+\beta_2x_{2t}+\beta_3x_{3t}+ (1+\phi)\epsilon_{t-1}-\phi\epsilon_{t-2}+\eta_t+\theta\eta_{t-1}.$$

Comment: You can write it that way. I just don't like the way $\epsilon_t$ does not show up, but $\epsilon_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_{t-2}$ do, which is why I stuck with writing down the regression and the ARIMA residual part separately.